# Passing string "@" as argument to GNU as macro?

Tags: macros, gnu-assembler

So I have this .S file, which is a minimal snippet (modulo actually compiling and linking) to show the problem:

```
.altmacro
.macro thing word
   .asciz "\word\()"
.endm

.section .rodata
.global data_stuff
.type data_stuff, %object

data_stuff:
    thing foo
    thing bar
    thing @
    thing baz
    .asciz "@"
```

The result of this in the final listing is:

```
  00004c94 <data_stuff>:
      4c94: 006f6f66 00726162 7a616200 ff004000     foo.bar..baz.@..
```

From this we see that the expansion triggered by `.altmacro` has done something undesirable with the `@` between `bar` and `baz`. Unfortunately, I need `.altmacro` expansion in some more complicated macros that include a `.asciz` directive.

How can I have the macro not expand a certain argument? I would prefer not to remove `.altmacro`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the correct syntax is:

```
thing \@
```